# Shape storage with postgres

Tags: postgresql, gis

I am dealing with storage of shapes. After a day spent to include the routines now I have some doubts.

The main trouble is recognize perfectly the new shape and know if already included or not.

I wrote something, and it works. I select all the shapes with same area and same number of vertex, and than I perform an Heuristic comparison. But, so just to be sure, I would ask you, if you know some direct algorithms, such matrix, spectrum, G theorm that gave two set of point can understand if the two sets are the same shape?

Before somebody screams about gis, the shapes can contain negatives shapes, better known with the name of holes. That are not to analyze in own coordinate system but in owner shape coord sys, where is the hole inside the other shape and his orientation. As far as I know, can gis nest shapes in other shapes and recognize them as whole shape.

Second place, what is the best way to store shape? I was thinking to store as array but I find it uncomfortable.

Comment: Can you provide some example? Maybe also migrate to gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sounds like you're working with abstract shapes often called *regions* and you want to union them, intersect them, add/subtract them, compare them, etc. Correct? Is this related to geography/GIS at all, or just abstract shapes?

Comment: Are steel sheets cuts. If for example, I have to store a flange, it is a big circle with a big hole inside it, and a lot of small holes for the bolts. If on another draw I select the same shape, oriented in another direction, I must be able to recognize that the two pieces are the same, and when ask for the resume, I get the counts. With vb.net, it is a class shape that contains a collection of negative shapes. But include this object in database, that is also the one that must check if already exists,  becomes hard. At first I thought, in a multidimension array, but it is not confortable.

Comment: Exactly for the flange I have the main trouble, because the positive shape get istantly checked, but the origin from wich I should  measure the vectord of distance and orientation,  is one  of the infinite points of the circumference. What I should I do? I thought something like linear algebra, but I cannot figure out the system. I agree to migrate to gis, but I would avoid to include an atomic arsenal just to push a mosquito. But I am very interested to know if there is small packages that can do it, and for sure how this get done with gis

Comment: Are your shapes 2D or 3D? You can describe any shape using [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text).